# Elastic Beanstalk has stopped logging to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm posting this as a question and answer, as I think many people may experience the same issue.

I've had an Elastic Beanstalk instance streaming logs to CloudWatch for over a year. Recently, my logs stopped appearing in CloudWatch. The Elastic Beanstalk instance is logging to its container correctly, and I have made no changes to my logging configurations.

Comment: This happens to me from time to time too. No idea what goes wrong. The only remedy I have found is to re-deploy the application - I have a configuration which allows seamless swaps between service instances.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

The most recent Java/Tomcat8 Elastic Beanstalk environment includes boto3. My .ebextensions/sshd.config file installs boto3, and this was causing a conflict. Removing the boto3 line from my sshd.config solved the issue.

**Full Answer**

I started my project as a Java/Tomcat Codestar template. This project includes the file .ebextensions/sshd.config which looks like this:

```
packages:
  yum:
    python27-devel: []
    python27-pip: []
    gcc: []
  python:
    pycrypto: []
    boto3: []
files:
  "/usr/local/bin/get_authorized_keys" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/awscodestar-remote-access-us-east-1/get_authorized_keys
commands:
  01_update_ssh_access:
    command: >
      sed -i '/AuthorizedKeysCommand /s/.*/AuthorizedKeysCommand \/usr\/local\/bin\/get_authorized_keys/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config &&
      sed -i '/AuthorizedKeysCommandUser /s/.*/AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config &&
      /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

The script installs python and boto3 into the Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Through AWS support I found out the latest Java/Tomcat environment already includes boto3, and trying to install this on top of the existing environment was causing a problem. This ultimately resulted in the instance logs failing to stream to CloudWatch.

The solution was simply to remove the explicit install of boto3 in the sshd.config, then **rebuild** the Elastic Beanstalk instance and redeloy my app.

I just tried creating a new Codestar Java/Tomcat template project, and the boto3 install line is still in the sshd.config.

I have not checked other types of project to see if the same sshd.config is included in the Codestar template. I assume this is probably not specific to the Java/Tomcat environment.